# Authentication Failed in Fedex Pickup Service

Tags: coldfusion, fedex

I am trying to implement the FedEx API. I have successfully run PickupAvailability with version v17, but the create pickup threw an authentication error with the same schema.

I am using XML created using documents and posting it to Postman. 
Code:

```
    <ns:CreatePickupRequest xsi:schemaLocation ="https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/downloads/xml/2018/advanced/ShipService_v23.xsd" xmlns:ns ="http://fedex.com/ws/pickup/v17" xmlns:xsi ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
         <ns:UserCredential>
            <ns:Key>XXXXXX</ns:Key>
           <ns:Password>XXXX</ns:Password>
         </ns:UserCredential>
     </ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
     <ns:ClientDetail>
         <ns:AccountNumber>XXX</ns:AccountNumber>
         <ns:MeterNumber>XXXX</ns:MeterNumber>

         <ns:Localization>
            <ns:LanguageCode>EN</ns:LanguageCode>
            <ns:LocaleCode>ES</ns:LocaleCode>
         </ns:Localization>
     </ns:ClientDetail>
     <ns:TransactionDetail>
         <ns:CustomerTransactionId>123456789</ns:CustomerTransactionId>
         <ns:Localization>
            <ns:LanguageCode>EN</ns:LanguageCode>
            <ns:LocaleCode>ES</ns:LocaleCode>
         </ns:Localization>
     </ns:TransactionDetail>
     <ns:Version>
        <ns:ServiceId>pickup</ns:ServiceId>
        <ns:Major>17</ns:Major>
        <ns:Intermediate>0</ns:Intermediate>
         <ns:Minor>0</ns:Minor>
     </ns:Version>
     <ns:OriginDetail>
            <ns:PickupLocation>
                <ns:Contact>
                        <ns:ContactId>123456</ns:ContactId>
                        <ns:PersonName>XXX</ns:PersonName>
                        <ns:Title>Mr.</ns:Title>
                        <ns:CompanyName>XXXX</ns:CompanyName>
                        <ns:PhoneNumber>XXXXXX</ns:PhoneNumber>
                        <ns:EMailAddress>XXXX</ns:EMailAddress>
                </ns:Contact>
                <ns:Address>
                    <ns:StreetLines>My Address</ns:StreetLines>
                    <ns:City>My City</ns:City>
                    <ns:StateOrProvinceCode>MD</ns:StateOrProvinceCode>
                    <ns:PostalCode>XX</ns:PostalCode>
                    <ns:CountryCode>US</ns:CountryCode>
                </ns:Address>
            </ns:PickupLocation>
            <ns:PackageLocation>FRONT</ns:PackageLocation>
            <ns:BuildingPart>DEPARTMENT</ns:BuildingPart>
            <ns:BuildingPartDescription>BuildingPartDescription</ns:BuildingPartDescription>
            <ns:ReadyTimestamp>T17:41:24-06:00</ns:ReadyTimestamp>
            <ns:CompanyCloseTime>17:00:00</ns:CompanyCloseTime>
            <ns:Location>NQAA</ns:Location>
            <ns:SuppliesRequested>SuppliesRequested</ns:SuppliesRequested>
    </ns:OriginDetail>
    <ns:PackageCount>1</ns:PackageCount>
    <ns:TotalWeight>
            <ns:Units>LB</ns:Units>
            <ns:Value>5</ns:Value>
    </ns:TotalWeight>
    <ns:CarrierCode>FDXE</ns:CarrierCode>
    <ns:OversizePackageCount>0</ns:OversizePackageCount>
    <ns:Remarks>test remark</ns:Remarks>
    <ns:CommodityDescription>TEST ENVIRONMENT -PLEASE DO NOT PROCESS PICKUP</ns:CommodityDescription>
    <ns:CountryRelationship>DOMESTIC</ns:CountryRelationship>
 </ns:CreatePickupRequest>
```

response:--

```
<v17:CreatePickupReply xmlns:v17="http://fedex.com/ws/pickup/v17">
<v17:HighestSeverity>ERROR</v17:HighestSeverity>
<v17:Notifications>
    <v17:Severity>ERROR</v17:Severity>
    <v17:Source>prof</v17:Source>
    <v17:Code>1000</v17:Code>
    <v17:Message>Authentication Failed</v17:Message>
</v17:Notifications>
<v17:TransactionDetail>
    <v17:CustomerTransactionId>123456789</v17:CustomerTransactionId>
    <v17:Localization>
        <v17:LanguageCode>EN</v17:LanguageCode>
        <v17:LocaleCode>ES</v17:LocaleCode>
    </v17:Localization>
</v17:TransactionDetail>
<v17:Version>
    <v17:ServiceId>pickup</v17:ServiceId>
    <v17:Major>17</v17:Major>
    <v17:Intermediate>0</v17:Intermediate>
    <v17:Minor>0</v17:Minor>
</v17:Version>
```

I am trying to authenticate the same way as PickupAvailability

Comment: You need to supply an example of the code that works, the code that doesn't work, and a screenshot of the dump when you get the error. Block out any access keys. We don't need to know your credentials. Also which version of ColdFusion are you using.

Comment: For others to be able to assist, you need to post your code and the actual error message.  Also, please see [Ask] and [MCVE].

Comment: sorry i  am upload  my code

Comment: xxxx is my authentication key and password and related to my credential that's why i write "xxxx"

Comment: A) What does the *successful* request (PickupAvailability) look like? B) What endpoint are you posting to? C) Did you verify the credentials (authentication key, password, etc..) are the same in both requests?

Comment: yes, everything is right. the service was not enable from FedEx side after i  mailed  for enable the service  on my side to FedEx that was enable and work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I found the solution. The service was not enabled for me, and was blocked from the Fedex side.

I sent an email to the Fedex support team asking them to enable the service. After they enabled it, it now works.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out, and thanks for posting the solution - in case anyone else runs into the same problem.